# Distribution of vector of balls in urns

Tags: probability

Suppose that I have $m$ balls and $n$ urns. I take each ball and randomly place it in an urn with no regard for where any other ball was placed or how many balls are already in the urn. I choose which urn according to a discrete uniform distribution over all $n$ urns.

The number of balls in a given urn is a binomial distribution with $p=1/n$.

But suppose that I want to describe the distribution of the $n$-element vector of counts of balls in each urn. I can't describe each urn as an independent binomial because I need the sum of all balls to be $n$.

Is there a simple way to describe this distribution without having to simulate all each ball individually?

Comment: See the [Multinomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [lulu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/252071/lulu) notes, what I was looking for was the [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).